# InDesign: How to restore text-frame position/size to be managed by the master page instead of the actual page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, designers, master-page

I have some designer that moved slightly a text-frame and in order to be managed again by the master page we need to remove the page and create a new one inserting the content in it.

Is there any different way to do it?

I would like to be able to restore the "power" of positioning/size to the master page because now we need to change the master-page to position the text-frame a little bit to the right and in the case above mentioned will not be updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the offending text frame, and open the Palette options in the Pages palette. Choose 'Master Pages' > 'Remove Selected Local Overrides'.

This makes the text frame obey the Master again. It does, however, also remove the frame's content and locks it again. You'll have to re-unlock it and re-add the content.

Comment: thanks this seems a the best way to do it... It would be a nice feature to indesign block the size and position of elements too.. but, thanks! (:

Comment: Is *that* what that does? I thought stripped out local text formatting. Ya learn something new every day. :)

Comment: It would be even more covenient if you could just select which features to override and which should obey the master from a tick list. Next version, maybe? @Lauren Ipsum: glad to be of service! :)

Comment: Caveat: If you select an overridden group, the `Remove Selected Local Overrides` menu item will change to `Remove All Local Overrides`. Yes, I think this is lame.

Answer (score 2):

In the Pages palette, drag the icon of a blank master page onto the icon of page you want to fix. This *applies* the blank master. Everything from the previous master page will disappear, and what will be left on that page will now be live, non-master, non-locked content.

Drag all that content into the pasteboard.

In the Pages palette again, drag the icon of the master page you want onto the icon of your page. This applies your chosen master page.

Copy or drag your content back onto the page as needed. You can unlock the master text frame and copy the content into it, and it should still be controlled by the master page.

Comment: I will try it, right now I don't have Indesign in front of me.. I will leave my feedback soon.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been faced with the same issue. I had too many items to replace (hundreds) so instead of resetting the master on each page, I added guides (by dragging from the ruler) on the master page to mark the centre point of my text areas.

Then, on each problem page I dragged the overridden text area to the correct position (which snaps into place..)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I think that would be very helpful ...

Comment: If you follow these instructions, you may be able to realign these elements *for now*, but if you change the master in the future, these page elements will not follow suit.

You should read this as, "I gave up on restore the elements' relationship s to the master, and this is what I did instead."